filepath.Ext не работает в termux
filepath.Ext()
Использование этой функции срабатывает при использовании на ПК на любой ос, но выдает пустоту когда пытаюсь получить расширение файла в термуксе на андроид. В чем проблема может быть и какие ещё данные нужны для понимания?
Код может быть любой, хоть
 log.Println(filepath.Ext(path))

в main.
Файл всегда один и тот же(я беру файл main.go моего проекта).
Может есть другой способ который даёт расширение всегда в любой ос.
UPD:
Проблема не в filepath.Ext а в mime.TypeByExtention. Именно эта функция дает путоту. filepath.Ext работает корректно
Посмотрел исходники как вообще реализовано определениие типа по расширению там это реализовано в виде мапы:
var builtinTypesLower = map[string]string{
    ".avif": "image/avif",
    ".css":  "text/css; charset=utf-8",
    ".gif":  "image/gif",
    ".htm":  "text/html; charset=utf-8",
    ".html": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
    ".jpeg": "image/jpeg",
    ".jpg":  "image/jpeg",
    ".js":   "text/javascript; charset=utf-8",
    ".json": "application/json",
    ".mjs":  "text/javascript; charset=utf-8",
    ".pdf":  "application/pdf",
    ".png":  "image/png",
    ".svg":  "image/svg+xml",
    ".wasm": "application/wasm",
    ".webp": "image/webp",
    ".xml":  "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
}

...и мне стало интреесно, а как же собственно, на остальных операционках определеяется тип данных файла, если в мапе исходников .go нет вовсе... Откуда mime.TypeByExtention берет text/x-go если такого расширения как .go нет в мапе в исходниках
UPD:
не разобрался откуда typebyextension из пакета mime берет text/x-go для .go файлов. Оказалось что не обязательно для текстовых файлов указывать точный тип. Для текстовых файлов достаточно указать text/plain и они почти везде будут обрабатываться нормально. Поэтому для определения типа использую DetectContentType из пакета http. Gemini говорит что typebyExtension из пакета mime это алиас над detectContentType из net/http.
Для моего кейса, определять тип с помощью http.DetectContentType() оказалось достуточно.

Для начала логичный вопрос — а хотя бы тот же log.Println(path) выводит хоть что-нибудь?

@andreymal логика функции такова, что сперва она выдает ошибку если файла нет. Поэтому версию, что файла нет я исключил

@andreymal ну вот что выводит на мой файл. Путь корректный. Файл на месте. /data/data/com.termux/files/home/cli-chat/main.go. это я ввел main.go и получил к нему абсолютный путь. Вот он. Но тип файла пустой.

@andreymal дополнил вопрос

Мой гугл не знает что такое os.TypeByExtention

@andreymal я кран. это mime.TypeByExtension. Извиняюсь, щас все исправлю

И что такое mime.TypeByExtention гугл тоже не знает, но тут хотя бы здравый смысл уже подсказывает как опечатку исправить

А как работает mime.TypeByExtension, написано прямо в документации, даже в исходники заглядывать не надо

@andreymal то есть получается что у меня в системе должна быть ассоциация расширения с типом данных, тогда typebyextension будет работать. Получается в термуксе этого не добиться такими срадствами...

Ну почему же не может? Добавьте интересные вам типы через функцию https://pkg.go.dev/mime#AddExtensionType

@PakUula либо скопировать содержимое /etc/mime.types debian и при запуске программы на Андроиде записать в /etc/mime.types термукса.  Буду пробовать.

Кстати, в Windows для расширения .go тоже нет типа MIME. mime.TypeByExtension(".go") в Windows возвращает пустую строку

@PakUula не разобрался откуда typebyextension из пакета mime берет text/x-go для .go файлов. Оказалось что не обязательно для текстовых файлов указывать точный тип. Для текстовых файлов достаточно указать text/plain и они почти везде будут обрабатываться нормально. Поэтому для определения типа использую DetectContentType из пакета http. Gemini говорит что typebyExtension из пакета mime это алиас над detectContentType из net/http. Еще выяснил что в официальных стандартах нет .go файлов. Это неофициальный тип.

Тип mime для .go задан в файле /usr/share/mime/globs2

@PakUula ну это уже при установке go добавляется.

Жаль что вы не привели минимально воспроизводимый пример. Из вашего примера совершенно неясно,откуда вы берёте path
Предположим, вы берёте его из os.Args. Но по какой-то неясной причине в Термуксе массив os.Args заполнен очень странно
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    log.Println(strings.Join(os.Args, " "))
    if len(os.Args) == 1 {
        log.Fatal("missing argument")
    }
    path, err := filepath.Abs(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to get absolute path", "path", os.Args[1], "error", err.Error())
    }
    log.Println(path)
    log.Println(filepath.Ext(path))
}

Программа выводит
~/zzz $ go build .
~/zzz $ ./zzz main.go
2024/11/03 18:33:47 ./zzz /data/data/com.termux/files/home/zzz/zzz main.go
2024/11/03 18:33:47 /data/data/com.termux/files/home/zzz/zzz
2024/11/03 18:33:47

В первой строчке напечатан массив os.Args:
os.Args[0] == ./zzz
os.Args[1] == /data/data/com.termux/files/home/zzz/zzz 
os.Args[2] == main.go

Если брать file.Ext(os.Args[1]),то результат действительно будет пустой строкой. Но если выполнить file.Ext(os.Args[2]), то вернёт, как полагается, .go.

Выше  написал что path это абсолютный путь.  В комменте к вопросу написал. То есть абсолютный путь точно верный /data/data/com.termux/files/home/cli-chat/main.go  но расширение пустое. Я щас написал определение расширения с помощью strings.Split(adsPath, ".") вернул точку+последний элемент получившегося  массива и получил ровно такое же поведение. На Линукс/виндовс все ок а в термуксе пустота в расширении. То есть на вход filepath.Ext() подаётся /data/data/com.termux/files/home/cli-chat/main.go

Все же проблема в другой функции. Я исправил вопрос. Проблема в mime.TypeByExtention а не в filepath.Ext. Именно TypeByExtention возвращает пустоту. Не понимаю как я не допер сразу. Но проблема актуальная
